# How do I make responsive Instagram captions in my code

Tags: php

I have an automatic post creator quote to Instagram, with the following code

```
$folder = "files/autoquotemaker/";

$overlay = $folder."overlay.png";
$font_quote = "files/_font/"."Chicle-Regular.ttf";
$font_copyright = "files/_font/"."KrinkesRegularPERSONAL.ttf";
$filename = $folder.md5(rand(000,999)).".png";
$quote = @$_POST['quote'] ? $_POST['quote'] : 'YOUR QUOTE';
$copyright = @$_POST['copyright'] ? $_POST['copyright'] : 'bacotangw9';
$usernameig = @$_POST['usernameig'] ? $_POST['usernameig'] : bacotangw__;
$backgrond = @$_POST['background'];
$caption = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$caption .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$caption = "Quotes dari @$usernameig \r\n
\r\n
yuk buat quotes mu sendiri dengan cara klik link yg ada di bio
\r\n
#quotes #quotestoday #qotd #quote #quotesoftheday #todayquotes #todayquote #dailyquotes #quotesdaily";
```

After entering Instagram, the caption is not as expected

What I hope for is like this

> "Quotes from @ $usernameig
>
> let's make your own quotes by clicking on the link in the bio
>
> quotes quotestoday qotd quote quotesoftheday todayquotes todayquote dailyquotes quotesdaily"

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: _is there something wrong in my code?..._ Your "code" isn't  actually "code" - you are just assigning strings to variables

Comment: What do you actually get, instead of the expected result? The code you've shown us does not output anything at all...do you do something more with those variables after you create them?

Comment: after I submit later, the photo will automatically post to Instagram but the caption is still in a mess, and I want to change the caption to be responsive

default:
Quotes from $usernameig, let's make your own quotes by clicking on the link in bio #quotes #quotestoday #qotd #quote #quotesoftheday #todayquotes #todayquote #dailyquotes #quotesdaily

which i want like this:

Quotes from @caca_0613
let's make your own quotes by clicking on the link in the bio

#quotes #quotestoday #qotd #quote #quotesoftheday #todayquotes #todayquote #dailyquotes #quotesdaily

Can it ?